# Getting "No module named wpf" when trying to run WPF with python 3.4 o VS2013 Express

Tags: wpf, ironpython

Hi i'm starting with Visual basic 2013 and Python. I've make some practicing with console applications with success. But when i tried to work with WPF, I see all the GUI while building. 
But when i try to debugg the application i get:

> No module named 'wpf'

I'm using Python 3.4 for debugging and I've tried to install the ironpython 2.7 and change the debugger in vs2013 but the error still persists.

What should i do? There's a way to install this module in python or it should be a bult-in module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run the program using IronPython/.NET as WPF will not be available in standard CPython environments.

You can check which python version you are running on e.g. by doing

```py
import sys
print sys.version
```

which will give you output like

> 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

or

> 2.7.3 (IronPython 2.7.3 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.34014 (64-bit))

depending on your chosen python interpreter.

If you are using [Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS)](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) you would right-click on the project, select *Properties* and under *General/Interpreter* ensure that IronPython is selected (and not CPython 3.4 you might be using). More on interpreters/environments can be found in [the documentation of PTVS](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Selecting%20and%20Installing%20Python%20Interpreters).